# Python Unit Test Start Directory Not Importable

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have encountered this error and tried a number of fixes posted on this site but have had no luck. I wrote a unit test and cannot call it due to the `Start Directory Not Importable` error. My file structure is:

```
Root
    └── tests
        └── fixtures
            └── customFile.json
        ├── __init__.py
        └── functionTest.py
    └── Lambdas
        └── FunctionA
            ├── __init__.py
            └── FunctionToTest.py
```

and my unit test looks like this:

```
import unittest
import json
import boto3

from Lambdas.FunctionA import FunctionToTest

s3 = boto3.client('s3', 'us-east-1')
file = s3.get_object(Bucket="BUCKET", Key="KEY")

mapper = s3.get_object(Key="KEY", Bucket="BUCKET")
mapperJSON = json.loads(mapper['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))

path = r"./tests/fixtures/customFile.json"
with open(path) as file:
    endList = json.load(file)
    file.close()

class TestMatchModeler(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_run(self):
        test = FunctionToTest(file, mapperJSON)
        self.assertEqual(len(test), len(endList))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and the actual code it's testing is:

```
def FunctionToTest(file, mapperjson):
    Fields = mapperjson['mappings']

    lines1 = file['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')
    fieldnames = lines1[0].replace('"','').split(',')
    testls = [row for row in csv.DictReader(lines1[1:], fieldnames)]
    out = json.dumps(testls)
    jlist1 = json.loads(out)

    dicts = []
    Fieldsinv = {v: k for k, v in Fields.items()}
    for i in jlist1:
        d = {}
        for k, v in i.items():
            if k in Fieldsinv:
                d[Fieldsinv[k]] = v
        d['individual_id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
        dicts.append(d)
    return dicts
```

Essentially the `customFile.json` is a list of dictionaries that I know are correct, and I want to test that my code modifies a CSV correctly to have the same number of dicts. This question has been asked a lot and the answer is always to have the files linked via an `init.py` file but as you can see I've done that and it still doesn't work.

I'm sure this may get flagged as a duplicate but im not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out running this command

```
python -m tests.functionTest
```

did the trick

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `__init__.py` files in some directories: root, tests and lambdas.

See here: [python - unittest - ImportError: Start directory is not importable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631667/python-unittest-importerror-start-directory-is-not-importable)

Comment: Hi @Artq99, I have added init files to each of those directories and I still get the same error unfortunately